# Android using Facebook login and EditText in the same activity?

Tags: android, android-edittext, facebook-login

I have an Activity that includes some EditText's for a self created login system and I've included a Facebook login button as well. When I comment out the section of FB code below from the activity I'm able to retrieve the values of the EditTexts. However, with the FB code all EditText values come back empty. Why is this?

```
public class LoginActivity extends FragmentActivity
{
  private EditText mEmailRegisterView;
  private EditText mPasswordRegisterView;
  private EditText mPasswordConfirmRegisterView;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Set FB fragment
    // Commenting this if/else allows the EditText values to be obtained.
    if (savedInstanceState == null)
    {
      // Add the fragment on initial activity setup
      loginFragment = new LoginFragment();
      getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .add(android.R.id.content, loginFragment).commit();
    }
    else
    {
      // Or set the fragment from restored state info
      loginFragment = (LoginFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
      android.R.id.content);
    }
    ...
    // Get the register EditText objects
    mEmailRegisterView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_activity_email_register);
    mPasswordRegisterView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_activity_password_register);
    mPasswordConfirmRegisterView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_activity_password_confirm_register);

    Button registerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register_button);
    registerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View view)
      {
        // Store values at the time of the login attempt.
        mEmailRegister = mEmailRegisterView.getText().toString();
        mPasswordRegister = mPasswordRegisterView.getText().toString();
        mPasswordConfirmRegister = mPasswordConfirmRegisterView.getText().toString();

        // These are all empty
        Log.d(TAG, "Email    : " + mEmailRegister);
        Log.d(TAG, "Password : " + mPasswordRegister);
        Log.d(TAG, "Confirm  : " + mPasswordConfirmRegister);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

If you need more code let me know.

Answer (score 0):

That is because of you **Store values at the time of the login attempt.** and after storing values you again assign your edittext in `onClick` method.So initialize editext only once in `onCreate` method instead of `registerButton onClick` method because **editext are part of activity layout** and will get null in `onClick` method,i.e. Change

```
  registerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
      // Get the current register EditText objects
      mEmailRegisterView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_activity_email_register);
      mPasswordRegisterView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_activity_password_register);
      mPasswordConfirmRegisterView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_activity_password_confirm_register);

      // Store values at the time of the login attempt.
      mEmailRegister = mEmailRegisterView.getText().toString();
      mPasswordRegister = mPasswordRegisterView.getText().toString();
      mPasswordConfirmRegister = mPasswordConfirmRegisterView.getText().toString();

      Log.d(TAG, "Email    : " + mEmailRegister);
      Log.d(TAG, "Password : " + mPasswordRegister);
      Log.d(TAG, "Confirm  : " + mPasswordConfirmRegister);
    }
  });
```

to

```
  registerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
    // Store values at the time of the login attempt.
      mEmailRegister = mEmailRegisterView.getText().toString();
      mPasswordRegister = mPasswordRegisterView.getText().toString();
      mPasswordConfirmRegister = mPasswordConfirmRegisterView.getText().toString();

      Log.d(TAG, "Email    : " + mEmailRegister);
      Log.d(TAG, "Password : " + mPasswordRegister);
      Log.d(TAG, "Confirm  : " + mPasswordConfirmRegister);
    }
  });
```

And define edittext (below lines) only once in your activity method

```
 // Get the current register EditText objects
          mEmailRegisterView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_activity_email_register);
          mPasswordRegisterView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_activity_password_register);
          mPasswordConfirmRegisterView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_activity_password_confirm_register);
```

Comment: I actually had that originally. I thought perhaps recreating the EditText objects when the click happened would allow me to get the values. No joy with either setup. IF that's the correct way to do it then I'll change my code above to reflect that. I'll add the private members as well.